# tshark not able to read icmp6 fields

Tags: networking, ipv6, wireshark, wireshark-dissector, tshark

I am able to read/replay all the headers and fields with tshark until hitting IPv6 header (ethernet header & IPv6 header), but when I am trying to replay the pcap files to read icmpv6 fields, nothing is being displayed of those fields.

Is this a bug of tshark? Is there any alternative tool to read all the fields in all headers of a packet?

The version of tshark I am using is 1.2.11

Comment: didnt find anything in wireshark help or google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bro](http://www.bro-ids) is a network traffic analysis tool with full IPv6 support, whereas tshark seems to struggle with IPv6. In Bro, you can get connection summaries by running it on a trace as follows:

```
bro -C -r trace.pcap
```

and inspect the resulting file `conn.log` in the same directory. You may find the accompanying tool `bro-cut` helpful to extract only a subset of the columns, e.g.,

```
bro-cut id.orig_h id.resp_h id.orig_p id.resp_p proto < conn.log
```

would extract the connection 5-tuple and print it to STDOUT, so that you can continue processing it with your favorite text munching tool.

Comment: Is this tool available for linux?

Comment: Yes, for all UNIX flavors. Just click on the link in the answer to learn more about it.